# Search data from dynamically created table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have created one application in that there is one text box for searching information from table. Although i have written the code when we enter the character in search text box, after accepting one character control goes out of textbox. 
this is my code for searching`

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var minlength = 1;

    $("#searchTerm").keyup(function () {
      
        value = $(this).val();
  
  if (value.length > minlength ) 
  {
   searchTable(value);
  }
  else if(value.length < minlength)
  {
   searchTable("");
  } 
 });
});
function searchTable(value)
{
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "dispatient.php",
  data:({search_keyword: value}),
  success: function(success)
  {
   window.location.href = "dispatient.php?search_keyword="+value; 
   $("#searchTerm").focus();
  },
  error: function() 
  { 
   alert("Error occured.please try again"); 
  },
  complete: function(complete)
  {
   $("#searchTerm").focus();
  },
  
 });
}
```

```html
<input id="searchTerm" Type="text" class="search_box"  placeholder="Search" 
      value = <?php echo $_GET['search_keyword'] ?> >
```

`
Please suggest to me..

thanks in advance..

Comment: No point in using AJAX if you are going to refresh the page, might as well use server side language.

Answer (score 1):

`value` is default attribute of javascript try to change the variable name of `value` into something like `searchData`

Comment: Thanks @narendra im change that value attribute but not still working plzzz help me

Comment: Sorry but didn't get you, try to check networks what you're getting over there

Comment: when i enter value in textbox its search after two words total page get refreshed and control goes out of textbox..

Answer (score 1):

In your success callback, you are redirecting the page to dispatient.php. I believe, this is the same page that has the search functionality. Once you redirect, the page is reloaded again and there is no point in writing:

```
$("#searchTerm").focus();
```

Since, you are already using AJAX, try loading the data from success on to your page through JavaScript/jQuery without reloading the page.

Comment: thanks for replyin to me.  when i enter in textbox value is but control is out of textbox ie page totally reloaded. sir please suggest any method.

Comment: sir how to stay in text in textbox

Comment: Remove the line window.location.href = "dispatient.php?search_keyword="+value; If you really want to reload the page then you need to find a way to get focus back to the search box after the page is reloaded. Though, I don't see the point of doing that. Please don't refer to me as sir, it's kinda embarassing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

create one div and load your data in that instead of reloading entire page.

try something like this instead of ajax Call

```
<div id="searchResult"></div>

$("#searchResult").load("search.php?search_keyword=value",function(){
//your callback
});
```